# Create fastify plugin for db connector with @fastify/mysql doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fastify

I'm trying to use fastify for my backend application and I would like to have my connection, my model, my controller and my routes separately like this :

```
backend/
│   ├── db/
│   │   ├── desecuDB.js
│   ├── models/
│   │   ├── desecuModel.js
│   ├── routes/
│   │   └── desecuRoutes.js
│   ├── controllers/
│   │   └── desecuController.js
│   ├── server.js
│   └── .env
```

I manage to launch my server but when I request /test I get this error.

`Error retrieving data from desecu DB: Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mysql')`

My connection to the database is done well because I see it from the SQL side and I have the connection message when my server is launched.
Is it correct to use fastify from this method ?
I have the impression that my desecuDB is not registered as a plugin in my instance.

My server.js :

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  logger: true
});

// Load environment variables
dotenv.config();

// Register database connections
fastify.register(require('./db/desecuDB'));

// Register routes
fastify.register(require('./routes/desecuRoutes'));

// Start the server
fastify.listen({ port: process.env.BACKEND_PORT }, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${fastify.server.address().port}`);
});
```

My desecuDB.js:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fp = require('fastify-plugin')

async function connectToDesecuDB(fastify) {
  fastify.register(require('@fastify/mysql'), {
    connectionString: `mysql://${process.env.DB_DESECU_USER}:${process.env.DB_DESECU_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_DESECU_HOST}/${process.env.DB_DESECU_DATABASE}`,
    name: 'desecu'
  })

  fastify.ready((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error connecting to the databases:', err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('Successfully connected to the databases');
  });
}

module.exports = fp(connectToDesecuDB);
```

My desecuRoutes.js:

```
const desecuController = require('../controllers/desecuController');

async function desecuRoutes(fastify, options) {
  fastify.get('/test', desecuController.getData);
}

module.exports = desecuRoutes;
```

My desecuModel.js:

```
async function getData(fastify) {
  try {
    const db = fastify.desecu;
    const result = await db.query('SELECT * FROM test');
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getData,
};
```

My desecuController.js:

```
const desecuModel = require('../models/desecuModel');

async function getData(request, reply) {
  try {
    const data = await desecuModel.getData(request.fastify);
    reply.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving data from desecu DB:', error);
    reply.code(500).send({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getData,
};
```

I followed the [Getting-Started](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Guides/Getting-Started#your-first-plugin) document but that uses mongoDB. If I group the whole thing only in my server.js my successful request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `desecuController.js` passes the `request.fastify` that does not exist and it is `undefined`.

You need to change that line to:

```
const data = await desecuModel.getData(this);
```

In a named function handler (as it is the `getData` function), the `this` context is equal to the fastify server instance - so the `desecuModel.js` function will be able to execute the `fastify.desecu` statement.

---

Note that the `desecuDB.js` file, the `ready()` usage is wrong.

```js
async function connectToDesecuDB(fastify) {
  await fastify.register(require('@fastify/mysql'), {
    connectionString: `mysql://${process.env.DB_DESECU_USER}:${process.env.DB_DESECU_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_DESECU_HOST}/${process.env.DB_DESECU_DATABASE}`,
    name: 'desecu'
  })
  console.log('Successfully connected to the databases');
}
```

note the `await fastify.register()` call that ensure the database connection, but it is not necessary this implementation unless you need to run some queries during the startup time.

All this is explained in the Fastify's book I wrote one month ago - see my profile for more info.

Comment: Alright ! Thanks for the help. I'm new to the product but I'll be sure to take a look at your book.